# Hibernate query get data in range of dates

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have the following query to get data within a range of dates and then order by the date:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(2014, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
Date b = cal.getTime();
cal.set(2014, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0);
Date e = cal.getTime();
String theQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT f FROM stuff f, IN(f.sess) as s WHERE s.time < :end AND s.time > :begin ORDER BY s.time";
Query query = em.createQuery(theQuery).query.setParameter("begin", b).setParameter("end", e);
```

I expect data like:

a | 2014-1-0 0:0:0:0
b |  2014-1-1 0:0:0:0
c | 2014-1-2 0:0:0:0
d | 2014-1-3 0:0:0:0

and so on, but i get data in a seemingly random order and not inside the date range specified. Does anyone have an idea of what I could be doing incorrectly?

Comment: How are you setting the parameters in the query?

Comment: @DavidWallace It is in the question: `query.setParameter("begin", b).setParameter("end", e);`

Comment: You do realize that your date range ends right before midnight of January 6th, right (i.e. you effectively exclude the 7th)? Hope that's intentional. Otherwise the range should be from 2014-01-01 00:00:00 to 2014-01-07 23:59:59. Furthermore I guess it should be `s.time >= :begin`. Try adding the data type to `setParameter` e.g. `setParameter("begin", b, TemporalType.DATE)`.

Comment: @MarcelStör Yeah you are right, I did not want to exclude anything, but either way the data returns dates from mid 2013 to far after January 7th, 2014. I added the date type as you suggested and nothing changed.

Comment: You need to verify what SQL statements Hibernate actually issues against the database -> [enable SQL logging in Hibernate](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/).

Comment: For my own learning, what does the IN(f.sess) syntax do? and shouldn't there be a join between s and f in the query?

Comment: @MarcelStör I have logging enabled but the log is odd and not helpful. I noticed on a print this query (not working) has the locale EDT and a different query I use has the locale EST (working). I never changed the locale, but am curious if this possibly means anything?

Comment: @JordanD, a few comments... "the log is odd and not helpful" - in my experience it's never the log that is odd but the code that produces/causes it, I suggest you take another look. Can you post (excerpts from) the log? Can you post what data the table in question contains? "I noticed on a print this query..." - don't understand what you want to say but EDT/EST are not locales but time zones.